# How to use GRASS command "r.stream.distance" in Qgis 2.16.2?

Tags: distance, grass-7.0, qgis-2.16, flow-accumulation, stream-order

I like to figure out the distance from each cell to the outlet along the flow path.
Maybe you can suggest some other opportunities/commands to solve my problem.
It would be nice, if someone can help me because i am a newcomer.

Comment: I used Qgis with Grass plugin but the r.stream.distance function isn´t shown in my toolbox. Is it anyway possible to add it there ?